# Carregar imagem somente quando clicar em um botão para exibir

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Pessoal fiz uma galeria de fotos um pouco grande então adicionei um efeito de `slice` nela são 64 imagens no caso quando o site carrega só aparece 12 e quando o usuário clica em ver mais vai aparecendo de 12 em 12 ele funciona normalmente segue o script do efeito:

```
$(".images-spaces").slice(0, 12).show();
        $("#loadMore-photos").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".images-spaces:hidden").slice(0, 12).slideDown();
            if ($(".images-spaces:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
```

o problema é que todas as 64 imagens carregam junto com o site e para otimizar isso queria que carregasse apenas as 12 primeiras que são as que eu deixei mostrando inicialmente  e queria que as imagens seguintes não fossem carregadas ao acessar o site e sim só quando eu clicar no botão de ver mais fotos:

```
<li class="col-md-2 no-padding all deck images-spaces" data-src="assets/images/gallery/deck-05.jpg">
                           <a href="assets/images/gallery/deck-05.jpg">
                               <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/gallery/deck-05.jpg" alt="Deck" />
                               <div class="gallery-ecoresort-poster">
                                    <p>Deck</p>
                                </div>
                           </a>
                       </li>

    <a href="#" id="loadMore-photos">Ver mais fotos</a>
```

ai no caso iria carregando de 12 em 12 gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso com essa galeria atual que tenho.

Comment: Com ajuda de PHP pode fazer tipo paginação

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar o `src` da imagem ou de varias como um atributo de um elemento e ao clicá-lo criar o elemento `<img>` através do javascript, 
segue um exemplo:

```js
function CarregaImagens(divDestino, data){
  var imagens = data.attr('imagens').split(",");
  var html = "";
  for(i=0;i<imagens.length;i++){
    html = html + "<img src='" + imagens[0] + "' width='5%'/>";
  }

  divDestino.html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" name="Btn" id="Btn" imagens="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1, https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1"
 onclick="CarregaImagens($('#imagens1'), $(this))">
    Exibe 12 Primeiras
  </button>
  <button type="button" name="Btn" id="Btn" imagens="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dy2j.jpg?s=328&g=1, https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NdO.jpg?s=128&g=1" onclick="CarregaImagens($('#imagens2'), $(this))">
    Exibe Próximas 12
  </button>
</div>
<div id="imagens1">

</div>

<div id="imagens2">

</div>
```

Comment: Isso não responde corretamente a pergunta, leia todo o texto que há na pergunta. Ele quer um script `Mostrar mais que carregue de 12 em 12 imagens`

Comment: Perdão, não tinha observado. Editei minha resposta.